# Azure Search Services not showing Indexes

Tags: azure, search, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

When trying to view (and later edit) indexes from the search services in Azure, I only get: The data is temporarily unavailable.  Any ideas on when this would be back up?  I was needing to make a pivotal change this AM for my client.

Comment: which region are you using?

Comment: location is EastUS